# MVC 5 Creating all elements of model that has one to one relationship with another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been searching and trying to figure this out on my own for a while now, and haven't been successful, so I'll see if someone can help me out here...

I'm building a MVC 5 web application with EF 6 Code-First. My 'Model1' contains a single "public virtual 'Model2'" (One to one relationship). Now, my issue is:

1. I need to be able to create a Model1 with it's associated Model2 in one View with the click of a single "submit" button.
2. I would need another view where one can open up the details for Model1 and then add a Model2 to it.

In other words: I have a Company that has an Address. Users should be able to create a new company with its related address, and separately, look at their company details and add an address if they don't already have one related to them.

I've managed to figure out Editing an existing address in a company, but haven't been able to figure out the other two things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If necessary, I can provide code to explain my situation more clearly.
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, some basic code would help - specifically, what do your controller actions look like? It's really difficult to understand from this where your problem lies but it likely has to do with misunderstanding either model binding or Entity Framework.

Comment: First, it's bad practice to use your entities directly in your view.  You should be using a View Model instead, and then mapping the results of your view model to entities in your back end.  Secondly, ViewModels allow you to wrap more than one model together into a single view.  Third, you don't actually have a 1 to 1 relationship, as that's not how EF maps 1 to 1's, you have a 1 to many in which you have just added a single entity.